# Why i use the method 'jQuery click event, after appending content' is not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I use jQuery Version 3.1.1, Why i use this method is not work ?

```js
$('input[name="images-post[]"').on("click", 'input[name="images-post[]"]', function() {
  $('.menu-create-post .mdi-camera').append('<input type="file name="images-post[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="span-wrapper" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="file" name="images-post[]"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Please correct the mistake :D

Comment: Why not try .live()

Comment: I think it will only work on the version, jQuery 1.3+

Comment: @AngularSan `live` event is deprecated long before `3.1.1`

Comment: @Firmansyah try after modifying click $('input[name="images-post[]"').on('click', function() { });

Comment: you need to bind click event again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code.

1. Live events must be binded to static elements, so `$(static).on('event', dynamic, function () {})`
2. You do not have elements that you try to append input element to.
3. Your `append` is missing `"` after `type="file`
4. Use domReady

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", 'input[name="images-post[]"]', function() {
    $('.menu-create-post .mdi-camera').append('<input type="file" name="images-post[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="span-wrapper" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="file" name="images-post[]"/>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="menu-create-post">
  <div class="mdi-camera"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, @Justinas :D, Very Awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

Just as @Justinas said, you have multiple errors in your dom. Delegate on click event is not better than change event for file input. Btw, you should delegate your event based on a static DOM, for a dynamic DOM.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.span-wrapper').on("click", '[name="images-post[]"]', function() {
    $('.mdi-camera').append('<input type="file" name="images-post[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="span-wrapper" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="file" name="images-post[]"/>
  </span>
  <span class="mdi-camera"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make bind event for click and simply call it whenever you need this.

```
function bindClick(){
     $('input[name="images-post[]"').unbind();
     $('input[name="images-post[]"').bind("click", 'input[name="images-post[]"]', function() {
         $('.menu-create-post .mdi-camera').append('<input type="file name="images-post[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">');
     });
}
```

Comment: Why it's better to re-bind event on every click? It will slow down code.

Comment: I accept it's not better always but, it is better when you do not want to make this click event on whole document. There is nothing to downvote.